# Denormalize data in AWS Glue PySpark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

Good day.

I have json data which I have successfully loaded into a dataframe.  It has the following format:

```
id: abc123
name: some_text
date: some_date
groups: aa,bb,cc,dd

id: def456
name: some_more_text
date: some_other_date
groups: dd,ee

...
```

I need to expand the data based on the groups field, so that instead of

```
abc123; some_text;      some_date;       aa,bb,cc,dd
def456; some_more_text; some_other_date; dd,ee
```

I get:

```
abc123; some_text;      some_date;       aa
abc123; some_text;      some_date;       bb
abc123; some_text;      some_date;       cc
abc123; some_text;      some_date;       dd
def456; some_more_text; some_other_date; dd
def456; some_more_text; some_other_date; ee
```

I was started by using the pyspark.sql function "split" which can split the groups into columns, but that is not quite what I need.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need both [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode)